# How to Pass a Variable to SEARCH database in Python - Sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am trying to pass a variable to search for the row from SQLite DB and print out the results. Here is the code below thats causing the problem:

```
find_domain = 'domain.com'

def searchdomain(locate):
    row = sql.execute("SELECT * FROM blocked_domains WHERE name = ?;",(locate,))
    print(row)

searchdomain(find_domain)
```

No error comes up, it just come back blank.

Comment: Are you sure that your sql statement returns any results?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have created a cursor object for data retrieval:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('tablename.db')
data = list(conn.cursor().execute("SELECT * FROM blocked_domains WHERE name = ?;", (locate,)))
```

Comment: When I try that, I get back []